# Is there any way to make the confirmation dialog stop appearing when clearing history in Safari?

Tags: safari, history

Every time I clear my history I am presented with a small alert window. Is there any way to avoid/disable this?

[image: History alert that I'd like to avoid]

Answer (score 1):

You could try the "Reset Safari" under Safari settings. Its right below Private Browsing (at least on my computer). you can uncheck everything but clear history. I tried it, and wasn't asked if i was sure I want to clear history.
[My source](http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/128527-annoying-safari-clear-history-window/page__view__findpost__p__848569)

Comment: Ehh, that's not what I'm looking for, sorry.